# Functions in a Function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have two for loop functions that are like that:

```
function displayblock() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount; ?>; x++) {
        document.getElementById("something" + x).style.display = "block";
    }
}

function displayinventorynot() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount2; ?>; x++) {
        document.getElementById("inventoryslot" + x).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Then i put these two functions in another function called test()

```
function test() {
    displayinventorynone();
    displayblock();
}
```

Now when i use the function "test" with a onclick html attribute it doesnt really work.
Basically only one of the two functions is being executed.
And its always the top one, so in this case it would be "displayinventorynone".
While "displayblock" is not executed at all.

Putting "displayblock" at the top means only displayblock is being executed and the other function not.

Why is this happening?

$amount is defined as 10 in a php file and $amount2 should be 5 or something.
Both elements are generated 10 or 5 times.

Comment: Unless you aren't getting the values from the php variables, then it really isn't php related and shouldn't be tagged as such.

Comment: debug the flow with alerts or console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably throws an exception in `displayinventorynone()` because there is no element with the id you specify. If you are on chrome try opening the developer console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I and then click on console at the top. It will show you the error there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a error in your code

```
function test() {
    displayinventorynone();   // Incorrect Name to call displayinventorynot
    displayblock();
}



function displayblock() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount; ?>; x++) {
        document.getElementById("something" + x).style.display = "block";
    }
}

function displayinventorynot() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount2; ?>; x++) {
        document.getElementById("inventoryslot" + x).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Sample code which works for you also `see comment for details`

```
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="something1" value="John" style="display:none;"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="inventoryslot1" value="Doe" style="display:block;"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit form" onclick="test();">


<?php

$amount = 10;
$amount2 = 5;
?>

<script>

function test() {

    displayinventorynot();
    displayblock();
}


function displayblock() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount; ?>; x++) {
        if(x==1){  // check to avoid TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null (no other id exist more than 1)
        document.getElementById("something" + x).style.display = "block";
      }
    }
}

function displayinventorynot() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= <?php echo $amount2; ?>; x++) {
        if(x==1){  // check to avoid TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null (no other id exist more than 1)
        document.getElementById("inventoryslot"+x).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

Comment: ah well i didnt made that mistake with "none" and "not" in my code tho. I will try it with this code.